# Width and value problems with rasterstats

Tags: error, rasterio, affine-transformation, rasterstats

I am trying to extract data from a raster with a gpkg file as a vector.
The issue is that, the data can't be extracted because the internal Bounding Box is negative. There I am not sure, whether this a bug, or my files are ill formatted.

In detail: I want to extract mean and the medium for the Polygons of the vector for a given raster file.

The CRS of the raster file is: EPSG:25833
the affine transformation is: Affine(1.0, 0.0, 379999.5, 0.0, 1.0, 5795999.5)

I am a computer scientist but I think this transformation is odd? Isn't e  of the affine transformation a negative number?

Example Polygon of the vector has the bounding box: (380670.907, 5796016.979, 380686.087, 5796057.668)
In it's **main.py rasterstats** calls: **rasterio's read** method. This one calculates the Bounding Box of the raster file to: ((58, 18), (671, 687)). Which has a **negative width** and therefore an Error is raised.

I found out when I manipulate the Affine transformation and set affine.e to -affine.e, then this error is not raised, but no statics is computed. This is due to the fact, that when the sub raster is extracted by:

```py
fsrc = rast.read(bounds=geom_bounds)
```

Calling rasterios read method my the main.py of rsaterstats, this returns a array with only nodata values set.

Is this a bug, or do I have to fix my files somehow? How do I do it?

Full example code:

```py
import numpy as np
from affine import Affine
from rasterstats import zonal_stats
from rioxarray import open_rasterio


raster = open_rasterio(r"path to elevation.xyz")
raster = raster.rio.write_crs(25833)


affine = raster.rio.transform()
affine2 = Affine(a=affine.a, b=affine.b, c=affine.c, d=affine.d, e=-affine.e, f=affine.f)
stats = zonal_stats(r'Path to levelo f detail.gpkg', np.squeeze(slope),
                    affine=affine2, layer="roofsurface", stats=['min', 'max', 'mean', 'median'])
```

Comment: In order to extract an AOI from a raster using a polygon you can look into the rasterio mask module, e.g. `rasterio.mask.mask` method works fine, have you tried that in place of the `rast.read` method you mentioned?

Comment: so far I surccomvient the problem by: reprojecting the raster from a resolution of (1,1) to (1,-1). But still do not understand, why that should cause a problem!

Comment: It is indeed strange that you get `Affine(1.0, 0.0, 379999.5, 0.0, 1.0, 5795999.5)`. It should be  `Affine(1.0, 0.0, 379999.5, 0.0, -1.0, 5795999.5)`, with `-1.0` . This might be what causes the problem..

Comment: Yes and no, the raster looks perfectly correct in QGIS. But as commented, preprojection with the resolution (1,-1) solves the problem.